# Calculate CPU percentage of a docker container based on CPUSTATS and PRECPUSTATS returned from ECS task metadata endpoint

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, devops, amazon-ecs

I was trying to calculate the CPU percentage of docker container that was currently up and running.

A call was made to ECS task metadata endpoint that returns a JSON file was Response which contains CPUSTATS, PRECPUSTATS, online_cpus, system_cpu_usage etc...

The formula that I usually using was as follows to calculate CPU percentages

```
Average cpu usage=((cpu_stats.total_usage - precpu_stats.total_usage) / (number of online cpu) )* 100.
```

And Dividng the Average cpu usage by difference between the read and preread timestamps as follows.

```
CPU PERCENTAGE= Average cpu usage/(read-preread).
```

But from the above calculation the percentage was not accurate it was returing  me a wrong value.

When checked the CPU usage in the host machine using ""docker stats" command it was showing correct results.

Is this correct way of calculating cpu percentages?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently working on container level metrics for aws ecs and came across this link which explains how to calculate CPU usage in percentage from the ecs metadata
[ECS-calculate-CPU-utilization-metadata-endpoint](https://shihtiy.com/posts/ECS-calculate-CPU-utilization-metadata-endpoing/)

This is the gist basically:

1. cpu_delta = cpu_stats.cpu_usage.total_usage - precpu_stats.cpu_usage.total_usage
2. system_cpu_delta = cpu_stats.system_cpu_usage - precpu_stats.system_cpu_usage
3. number_cpus = length(cpu_stats.cpu_usage.percpu_usage) or cpu_stats.online_cpus

Finally:

CPU usage % = (cpu_delta / system_cpu_delta) * number_cpus * 100.0

I am going to implement this right now. This will give the increase or decrease in cpu usage from last sampling time.